# 403 Error - Thats an error. Error: disallowed_useragent when trying to log in to google in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-signin

I am currently trying to implement google login in my Xamarin forms app. I use this project: https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Google-Login-Xamarin-Forms

However I get this error when I open the web view:

```
403 Error - Thats an error. Error: disallowed_useragent
```

When I research this I read that google has stopped its webview login. 
So my question is, what other solution is there right now for Xamarin forms? Is there an optional solution to make the webview work or is there a Google SDK that handles login?

I have not found any example of this when I research.

Comment: There is an alpha version of `Xamarin.Auth` that supports `ChromeCustomTabs` and `SFSafariViewController` but honestly there are huge problems with that code right now (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth), that project needs more Microsoft/Xamarin attention and love. There are Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android native Google auth/login packages available that you can use via dependency services.

Comment: Ok alright! Is there a Xamarin.ios dependency example out there somewhere?

Comment: I plan to implement it in Xamarin forms so I would do a custom renderer on each platform

Comment: After a year of work with Xamarin.Forms I can say that is way to implement most simple client-server relations and common simple UI. Conclusion: Xamarin is ROAD TO HELL!